# What is an equivalent to saying "for the purpose of this essay"?

Tags: expressions, synonyms

I cannot think of another formal way to say "for the purpose of this essay." 
The following sentence shows some context:

> For the purpose of this essay, it is not necessary to dwell any further on particular conditions...

Answer (score 3):

I agree the phrase is worth avoiding; but avoiding it does not require any substitute. The sample sentence of which you offer the first part almost certainly deserves to be deleted entirely during revision. Resist temptations to talk *about* your essay *within* your essay. (One exception might be a [*partitio* or *divisio*](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Canons/Arrangement/Partitio.htm) section offering an advance road-map to a particularly complicated argument.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a phrase similar to "outside the scope of this essay"

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @Anon. When you have enough [rep](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) such a short post could be made as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The English adverb *herein* may serve.   From [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/herein#Adverb), it means “Within this content, context, or thing”.  You could say:

> it is not necessary to dwell herein any further on particular conditions

or could say

> Those conditions need not be considered here

but for brevity might instead say “I'll say no more of this now” or use an old standby, “But I digress”.

Of course, as Brian Donovan has noted in an answer, there's little need in an essay – a fairly short work – for such a sentence at all.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes say:

> For present purposes